# Dynamically Creating and Removing Pages in jQuery Mobile 1.4.4

Tags: jquery-mobile

After I create some page dynamically and insert it into `body`, what should I run to let the jquery mobile know that this page is new in order to initialize (or whatever jquery mobile needs to do with it)?
How to remove the page dynamically (and let jquery mobile know, if that is needed)?

I am aware of `$.mobile.initializePage()`. This goes through all the pages and do something on them. I was hoping that there is something that can be done only on the new page. Is it?

If this is relevant I am using Pagecontainer widget to do all the navigation.

Comment: If you inject a page into Dom, you don't have to initialize it, JQM will initialize it before showing. Removing a page from Dom, doesn't remove it from navigation history, hence, you'll need to manipulate navigation on `pagecontainerbeforetransition`.

Comment: When JQM initialize it before showing, can this be a performance problem? If so, I would prefer to initialize this page long before going to it. Actually I have bunch of pages which I will insert and I would like to initialize them all at the same time.

Comment: In this case call `.page()` however I don't think it's going to affect performance. All pages static and dynamic are initialized before being shown. `pagebeforecreate`.

Comment: Thanks! You can put all that into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'll prepare a comprehensive answer.

Comment: btw, what do you mean by "How to remove the page dynamically _(and let jquery mobile know, if that is needed)?_" Pages can be removed, but what do you mean by needed?

Comment: It is easy to remove `div` from the DOM that defines the page. But then, is there something that I should do to tell JQM what I just did? Maybe JMQ needs to know that to clean some stuff in the background (I am just assuming)? Or maybe JQM just provides some method to remove a page from the DOM that I should just use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63563/discussion-between-omar-and-dartfish).

Comment: demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/34vraba0/

Comment: I am not concerned about history. So, for removing a page I guess it is enough to do something like `$('#mypage').remove()`?
in your fiddle I see you use `.enhanceWithin()`. Should `.enhanceWithin()` be used instead of `.page()`?